# Convert the values for a column relating to an ID to an additional row

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a table with 3 columns ID, clinical condition 1 and clinical condition 2. The table is shown below

```
ID  clinical condition 1    clinical condition 2
2345    depression          dementia
2346    Tuberculosis    
2347    cancer  
2348    Flu                 dementia
```

I would like to make the following transformed table using base R

```
ID  clinical condition 1    
2345    depression          
2345    dementia
2346    Tuberculosis    
2347    cancer  
2348    Flu                 
2348    dementia
```

Can someone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here rather than a table in your question. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Apologies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in base R:

```
subset(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1])[-2]), nzchar(values))
    ID       values
1 2345   depression
2 2346 Tuberculosis
3 2347       cancer
4 2348          Flu
5 2345     dementia
8 2348     dementia

subset(reshape(df, list(2:3), dir="long"), nzchar(clinical_condition_1))
      ID time clinical_condition_1 id
1.1 2345    1           depression  1
2.1 2346    1         Tuberculosis  2
3.1 2347    1               cancer  3
4.1 2348    1                  Flu  4
1.2 2345    2             dementia  1
4.2 2348    2             dementia  4
```

in Tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-ID)%>%
   filter(nzchar(value))
# A tibble: 6 × 3
     ID name                 value       
  <int> <chr>                <chr>       
1  2345 clinical_condition_1 depression  
2  2345 clinical_condition_2 dementia    
3  2346 clinical_condition_1 Tuberculosis
4  2347 clinical_condition_1 cancer      
5  2348 clinical_condition_1 Flu         
6  2348 clinical_condition_2 dementia
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 2345:2348, clinical_condition_1 = c("depression", 
"Tuberculosis", "cancer", "Flu"), clinical_condition_2 = c("dementia", 
"", "", "dementia")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```